# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\r'

Tags: python-3.x

I am actually trying to convert a character to a integer. 
(i.e '1' to 1 ) in python3 but it is showing some error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\r'
```

why it is unable to convert it.
if i am running it on geeksforgeeks compiler it is not showing any error.
But on submittion it shows this error.

```
t=int(input())
for each in range(t):
s=input()
count=0
num=0
for eachch in str(s):
    if (eachch>='a') and (eachch<='z'):
        count+=1
    else:
        num=num*10+int(eachch)
if(int(num) == int(count)):
    print("1")
else:
    print("0")
```

Tell me why this is happening and also the difference between these compilers.

Comment: `\r` is a CR character -- a carriage return. They tend to show up when you have input built on a DOS/Windows platform (where lines end with CRLF, aka `\r\n`) being fed to a program running on a UNIX platform (where lines end only with LF, aka `\n`).

Comment: @Piyush Yadav, You should fix indents in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here must be that input string you get has `\r` symbol, so `int()` function can't get an integer out of this. Using `strip()` function must help here.

I.e. `t = int(input().strip())`